# Unknown chars in va_list?

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void s(const char* param, ...)
{
    va_list arguments;
    va_start (arguments, param);
    const char* param_now = va_arg(arguments, const char*);

    while(param_now != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", param_now);
        param_now = va_arg(arguments, const char*);
    }

    va_end (arguments);
}

int main()
{
    s("one", "two");
    return 0;
}
```

Why my code above doesn't work and displays unknown symbols instead of one and two?

**Edit**: found a pretty smart way to avoid including NULL at the end:

```
void add_s(const char* param, ...)
{
    return s(param, NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never terminated your sequence with a NULL parameter, what your while loop is checking for.

```
s("one", "two" , NULL );
```

Now only "two" appears. That is beacuse the first string is in parameter `param`.
So you have to first print it, and then print all the optional parameters.

You can use a macro to avoid writing the NULL terminator. Something like:

```
#define my_s( ... )    s( __VA_ARGS__ , NULL )
```

Note that this requires at least one argument in `my_s`. ( and think about avoiding using macros in serious code )

Comment: Cool thanks. Is there any way to avoid adding NULL at the end, by getting the number of arguments somehow?

Comment: @Luka: Without an explicit termination parameter at the end, the only remaining option is to use a starting parameter that describes the remaining parameters to your loop.  In this case, that starting parameter can be a simple counter, eg: `void s(int numParams, ...)` then `s(2, "one", "two");`

Comment: "and think about avoiding using macros in serious code" why?

Comment: @Luka: because they are easy to abuse and misuse. Plus, you are using C++, so there are better options available, such as `<<` stream operators, variadic templates, etc.

Comment: variadic templates are godsend but VS2012 doesn't support them and I believe (correct me if I am wrong) it's better to avoid new language features when possible because the compiler writers won't get them perfect the first time.